# trace view not show up in eclipse ddms

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, ddms

I did method profiling and generated .trace file in ddms but when I tried to open it, eclipse didn't display the file. I viewed trace file b4 but had closed the view window by mistakes. How to get the trace view window back? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happens sometimes when it has running process in background.
so try to Kill Process in Task Manager or restart system.